# My Asp.net core app Event handlers not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, events, dependency-injection, onion-architecture

I'm creating an ASP.net Core application with onion architecture.I want to raise some events in Business Logic layer and subscribe to these events from infrastructure layer.(layers from inner to outer: Domain - Contracts - Business Logic - Infrastructure - API)

one of my BL classes and event implementation:

```
public class LiveStreamBusinessLogic : ILiveStreamBusinessLogic
    {
       
        public event ILiveStreamBusinessLogic.LiveStreamEventHandler LiveStreamEventOccured;        
        
        public async Task<IBusinessLogicResult<PagedList<LiveStreamForShowDto>>> GetAllLiveStreamAsync(LiveStreamParameters liveStreamParameters)
        {
            // some logic
            OnDomainEventOccured();
            return new BusinessLogicResult<PagedList<LiveStreamForShowDto>>
                {Success = true, Result = livesListForTransferPaged};
        }

        

        protected virtual void OnDomainEventOccured()
        {
            LiveStreamEventOccured?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        
    }
```

also i'm using DI for creating upper class with this interface :

```
public interface ILiveStreamBusinessLogic
    {
        public delegate void LiveStreamEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs args);
        public event LiveStreamEventHandler LiveStreamEventOccured;

        Task<IBusinessLogicResult<PagedList<LiveStreamForShowDto>>> GetAllLiveStreamAsync(LiveStreamParameters liveStreamParameters);
        
    }
```

and this class will instantiated through StartUp class:

```
services.AddScoped<ILiveStreamBusinessLogic, LiveStreamBusinessLogic>();
```

and my subscriber is :

```
public class ElasticLogger
    {
        private readonly ILoggerManager _loggerManager;
        private readonly ILiveStreamBusinessLogic _liveStreamBusinessLogic;

        public ElasticLogger(ILoggerManager loggerManager, ILiveStreamBusinessLogic liveStreamBusinessLogic)
        {
            _loggerManager = loggerManager;
            _liveStreamBusinessLogic = liveStreamBusinessLogic;
            Subscribe();
        }

        private void Subscribe()
        {
            _liveStreamBusinessLogic.LiveStreamEventOccured += OnDomainEventOccured;
        }
        
        private void OnDomainEventOccured(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _loggerManager.LogInfo(Serialize(e).ToString());    
        }
        
    }
```

and StartUp :

```
services.AddScoped<ElasticLogger>();
```

the problem is event will raise correctly but the handler does not execute. I guess there is a problem with the procedure of instantiating my classes in startup but have no idea how to solve it? any solution or even better pattern for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your example codes here, I cannot see that you are creating an instance of the `ElasticLogger`. That means no `ElasticLogger` is created, therefore it couldn't `Subscribe`.

You can check if my theory is correct or not, by putting a breakpoint in the constructor of `ElasticLogger`. If you never hit the breakpoint, then I'm right.

I suggest you to refactor `ElasticLogger`, don't call `Subscribe` from the constructor. But do like this:

```
public class ElasticLogger
{
    private readonly ILoggerManager _loggerManager;
    private readonly ILiveStreamBusinessLogic _liveStreamBusinessLogic;

    public ElasticLogger(ILoggerManager loggerManager, ILiveStreamBusinessLogic liveStreamBusinessLogic)
    {
        _loggerManager = loggerManager;
        _liveStreamBusinessLogic = liveStreamBusinessLogic;
    }

    public void Subscribe()
    {
        _liveStreamBusinessLogic.LiveStreamEventOccured += OnDomainEventOccured;
    }

    private void OnDomainEventOccured(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _loggerManager.LogInfo(Serialize(e).ToString());
    }
}
```

But, make sure you call it externally, after your application starts, call it like: `elasticLogger.Subscribe()` externally. Then your event should be handled.

Comment: Thanks. You were right. There was a problem with constructing. I fixed it and right now it works properly.